IS TRUE operator
How strict is the IS TRUE SQL operator supposed to be? For example, BigQuery only allows an actual BOOL value, whereas every other dialect I've seen allows numerics as well, for example mysql or postgres allows select '1' is true, though perhaps that's just for historical reasons because many databases don't include an actual BOOL data type.
What then should the IS TRUE operator allow as the operand?

You've tagged this as database -agnostic, but then demonstrated that IS TRUE is not. I'm not sure what answer you're expecting.

I checked the ANSI-92 standard, and did not even see IS TRUE mentioned.  In addition, it appears that not every major database supports IS TRUE (e.g. SQL Server).

@TimBiegeleisen IIRC, IS TRUE is a feature of SQL-99.

In the PostgreSQL case, '1' is a BOOL.

@BillKarwin Thanks for the good research.  Enjoy the upvote!

@ry -- not really. '1' is a string, though Postgres allows coercing certain strings to bools when it expects that type. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html#DATATYPE-BOOLEAN.

@David542: But at the same time, really. PostgreSQL allows coercing all ”strings” to anything according to context, in a way that makes them effectively untyped literals.

(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS: “A cast applied to an unadorned string literal represents the initial assignment of a type to a literal constant value, and so it will succeed for any type (if the contents of the string literal are acceptable […]). An explicit type cast can usually be omitted if there is no ambiguity as to the type that a value expression must produce (…); the system will automatically apply a type cast […]. However, automatic casting is only done for casts that are marked “OK to apply implicitly” in the system catalogs.”)

Strictly by the SQL-99 standard, IS may compare only to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.  Read https://sql-99.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapters/09.html for details.
Any vendor's implementation may diverge from the standard. In MySQL for example, true is just an alias for the integer 1, and false is an alias for the integer 0.
mysql> select true is true;
+--------------+
| true is true |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select 1 is true;
+-----------+
| 1 is true |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select '1' is true;
+-------------+
| '1' is true |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

SQLite also permits some flexibility in data types.
sqlite> select true is true;
1
sqlite> select 1 is true;
1
sqlite> select '1' is true;
1

PostgreSQL is in between. A string '1' is treated as true, but the integer 1 is not a valid operand:
postgres=# select true is true;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select '1' is true;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select 1 is true;
ERROR:  argument of IS TRUE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: select 1 is true;
               ^

SQL implementations always have their own idiosyncrasies. You need to study the documentation for the respective brand you use, and even the exact version.

thanks, even SELECT -23.4 IS TRUE returns 1 in mysql, as does SELECT 'a' IS FALSE, so it's even more permissive than the above indicates.

Boolean test is an optional SQL standard feature (F571, Truth value tests), for boolean values only.
The SQL:2023 (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023(E)) syntax:
<boolean test> ::=
  <boolean primary> [ IS [ NOT ] <truth value> ]

<truth value> ::=
    TRUE
  | FALSE
  | UNKNOWN

<boolean primary> ::=
    <predicate>
  | <boolean predicand>

<boolean predicand> ::=
    <parenthesized boolean value expression>
  | <non-parenthesized value expression primary>

<parenthesized boolean value expression> ::=
    <left paren> <boolean value expression> <right paren>


